# Sort Column ASC/DESC: SQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql

There is a mistake causing it not to flip between ASC/DESC and I am 90% sure it is within these few lines.. I think I need to have a "first" loop that will "save" $sort so it flips later. But when I do this it causes an array error then.

The SQL is more than likely correct...
I am NOT worried about SQL Injections/PDO/security yet as I am adding that code in later.

Full Link: https://solenoidal-slate.000webhostapp.com/

```
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
$sort = $_GET['sort'];
} else {
    $sort='ASC';
}

$sort == 'DESC' ? $sort ='ASC': $sort='DESC';
$query = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY $order $sort";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query); ?>

<th><a class="column_sort" id="id" href='?order=id&sort=$sort'>ID<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span></a></th>
```

This above line is an example of a column that is "Getting" the $sort variable.

EDIT: To save time, $order is not the issue.. Each column name is sorting by column successfully.

```
  if(isset($_GET['order'])){
    $order = $_GET['order'];
    } else {
    $order = 'id';
    }
```

Comment: You are setting `$order` to `ASC`.  I doubt that is a column name.  As with most problems of this sort, looking at the code after variable substitution would generally solve the problem.

Comment: if(isset($_GET['order'])){
$order = $_GET['order'];
} else {
$order = 'id';
}

Comment: are you sure you have not error  ?

Comment: Gordon, I fixed the small typo I found which helped (got rid of an error) but still does not sort ASC/DESC. THanks for finding that typo.

Comment: Do you realize that     $sort == 'DESC' ? $sort ='ASC': $sort='DESC';   is useless?  If the $_GET is set, you take that value, if not you take ASC (your default).

Comment: Yeah haha I actually thought it was useless... I was told to put ASC in case an error happened but often deleted it (seeing it actually did anything). Guess I should add a column example too so people can see my get sort "a href".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
$sort = ($sort == 'DESC') ? 'ASC': 'DESC';
```

and write only one "&" between query string key/value pairs:

```
<a ... href="?order=id&sort=$sort">
```

and apply php code properly in the "href". Otherwise you'll have `$sort` as html code too.

So, I would do it like so for example:

```
<?php

$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'id';
$sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'ASC';

$sort = ($sort == 'ASC') ? 'DESC': 'ASC';

$query = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY $order $sort";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query); ?>
//....
?>

<th>
    <a class="column_sort" id="id" href="?order=id&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">
        ID<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span>
    </a>
</th>
```

Or you could use this directly:

```
<?php

//...
$sort = ((isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'ASC') == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

$query = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY $order $sort";
//...
```

Comment: Well that was one issue but it is still sorting DESC.

Comment: Ok thanks I changed your edit but it still does not ASC/DESC. Someone with a high reputation told me to try two && at one point (which I thought it was only &).

Comment: Your new edit with <?php echo $sort; ?>   makes total sense and I have some confidence this could completely fix it... I am just working on the correct syntax may take a few minutes...

Comment: @ScottSchmidt You have wrong html code! 2 anchors in one "th"!

Comment: done! thanks. Will +1 and mark as answer once I get 3 more reputation, haha. I lost some reputation this week unfortunately, haha. THANKS SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

Your final code would be something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['order'])) { // Check $_GET['order'] is in the predefined array
    $order = $_GET['order'];
} else {
    $order = 'id';
} 

if(isset($_GET['sort'])) { // Preferably you can check this also in_array($_GET['sort'], ['ASC', DESC])
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
} else {
    $sort = 'ASC';
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY $order $sort";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

#### Update:

Your link needs to be changed,

It should be like this http://solenoidal-slate.000webhostapp.com/?order=id&sort=DESC or ASC and remove one `&` from the link

Now it's like this: https://solenoidal-slate.000webhostapp.com/?order=id&&sort=$sort

Comment: That's what I currently have... Or maybe I am missing the difference.

Comment: This is the url: https://solenoidal-slate.000webhostapp.com/?order=id&sort=$sort see the value of sort paramater is PHP varable not its value

Comment: And also you put two `&` hopefully this is not an issue

Comment: Ya just updated the &.  Ok and good point. Yeah I don't think the $sort is saving which is why I think I may need $sort nested within a loop so it "saves"

Comment: if you put like this: solenoidal-slate.000webhostapp.com/?order=id&sort=DESC it works

Comment: Interesting very cool analysis... well I must be very close then. Looks like the $sort just isn't getting pushed correctly.

Comment: Yeah! that's the exact problem you're facing

Comment: Ya I will try to put $sort == ('Desc') into a nested loop again. Maybe it will work this time as I fixed other minor things.

Comment: Ok, Perfect! Have Fun :)

Comment: Between you and Aend I did! I did not have to make a nested loop like I possibly thought... had to do a <th>
    <a class="column_sort" id="id" href="?order=id&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">
        ID<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span>
    </a>
</th>

Comment: thanks for all help! I will plus one you once I get 15 reputation I am one short ha.

Comment: Cool I can plus 1 yall before I lose it haha. thanks

Comment: **@ScottSchmidt** great! thank you so much, all the very best.

Comment: I have a very easy question if you guys want more points (haha): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994625/drop-down-menu-click